# Getting old filesystem events - check which process deleted a specific folder

Tags: upgrade, filesystem, file

After macOS minor upgrade of Monterey I've noticed that a directory of mine has been deleted. is there a way to check in retrospect which process deleted my directory ?

I know of fsevents, but it's used to record ongoing file activities... the question is how to get file auditing event from the past.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1755225/file-auditing-in-macos-check-which-process-deleted-a-folder-file

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no such logging by default which would show you which program deleted a specific directory in the past.

Comment: Hi @jksoegaard and thanks for the info... Perhaps do you know if there's any process that can run in the background as deamon, that can monitor file events at all times (even during login window) ?

Comment: Yes, sure there are many programs like that. For example Time Machine backups works on a similar basis. You can't install them after the fact and get information about the past though.